# How can I find what process/code is removing outlook attachments?

Tags: outlook, ms-office, office-interop

Users of my add-in have an intermittent problem where some attachments are removed during/after send is pressed. I.e. They add attachments to an email, send it, then the some attachments are not present on the email in sent items, nor at the recipient.

I've added logging to my add-in that shows the AttachmentRemove event is fired on the MailItem milliseconds before the MailItem Send event fires.

I guess that another add-in, or outlook itself is removing the attachments, but I'm not sure how to identify the root cause.

Are there any tools that can help me diagnose this intermittent problem in a production environment?

- Are the outlook etl log files likely to include relevant information? If so is there a tool to interpret them? (Event viewer can open, but doesn't seem to have meaningful info.)
- I've seen reference to OutlookSpy, but it doesn't appear suitable as a production logging tool.

I am going to ask users to try disabling all other add-ins, but if that fails what then? I'm considering trying to capture more information by either 1) writing a new logging add-in with a ProgId to have it's events fired first or 2) Programmatically capturing a minidump/call stack when AttachmentRemove is fired. However I hope there are simpler alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

You need to disable all COM add-ins and VBA macros in Outlook.